# Realm Observable not finishing when using rx-java amb() or switchIfEmpty()

Tags: android, realm, rx-java, rx-android

When using Realm Observable by calling `asObservable()` on the query, with `amb()` or `switchIfEmpty()` cause the realm's observable to not finish its sequence. A work around to this can be done by using `Observable.just()` instead of Realms `asObservable()`.

I cant figure out if this is caused by my code or a bug in rx-java or Realm.

```
      mSubscription = getRealmObservable(params).switchIfEmpty(getNetworkObservable(params))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(subscriber);

}

private Observable<model> getNetworkObservable(UrlParams params) {
    final api service = NetworkManager.getAPI();
    return service.getModel(params.toMap())
            .doOnNext(new Action1<RealmList<Model>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(RealmList<Model> models) {
                    if (models != null && models.size() > 0) {
                        mRealm.beginTransaction();
                        mRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(models);
                        mRealm.commitTransaction();
                    }
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<RealmList<Model>, Observable<Model>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Model> call(RealmList<Model> models) {
                    return Observable.from(models);
                }
            });
}

private Observable<Model> getRealmObservable(final UrlParams params) {

    return Observable.just(mRealm.where(Model.class).findAll())/*.asObservable()*/ <- Using this cause this sequence not to finish
            .filter(new Func1<RealmResults<Model>, Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public Boolean call(RealmResults<Model> models) {
                    return models != null && models.isValid() && models.size() > 0;
                }
            })
            .flatMap(new Func1<RealmResults<Model>, Observable<Model>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Model> call(RealmResults<Model> models) {
                    return Observable.from(models);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Are you using findAllAsync().asObservable()?

Comment: No, as the code snippet shows, i use findAll().asObservable()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The observable created by calling asObservable() on RealmResults will never terminate (call onComplete). See the documentation [here](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmResults.html).